How to use binding variables in an Oracle query?
I have an Oracle query written using binding variables:
SELECT
    t.id ID,
    t.name NAME,
    sum(CASE WHEN t.BE_VALIDTO IS NULL AND t.DATE >= :StartDate AND t.DATE <= :EndDate and t.TYPE in (:type) THEN t.AMOUNT END) MONTH,
    (sum(CASE WHEN t.BE_VALIDTO IS NULL AND t.DATE >= :StartDate AND t.DATE <= :EndDate and t.TYPE in (:test) THEN t.AMOUNT END) + :'t.id') INCEPTION
FROM
    table t
WHERE
    t.tenantid = :tenantId
    AND t.id in (:accountIds)
GROUP BY
    t.id,
    t.name

The params are as follows:
[tenantId:50129, 16336:1, StartDate:01-Jul-24, EndDate:10-Jul-24, test:Sweep Purchases , accountId16336:16336]
In the query the ":t.id" in green is key '16336' in the params. How do I pass this in the query correctly.
If I execute the query the way it is right now, it gives me "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name".

Post full error text.

If you're using Java, then please post Java code

What is ... + :'t.id' supposed to be doing?

sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

t.id should be the id from the select query.

Then why does it have the : to make it a bind variable, and why is it enclosed in quotes? Neither looks right. Doing ... + t.id doesn't seem to make sense either - you're summing up amounts, then adding the ID? That seems... odd.

Firstly please confirm it works in SQL Plus. It should be a prerequisite to discussing the Java angle. If it doesn't then the Java angle is not (yet) relevant
